# Accessing Foreign Key values from a foreign key referenced model in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Models

```
class Ride(models.Model):  
    type = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ride_comment = models.TextField(null=True,max_length=140,blank=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.ride_comment

class Driver(models.Model):
    ride_id = models.ForeignKey(Ride)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    drv_carseats = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True,blank=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user_id.username
```

Here is the Views.py

```
def search(request):
        result_list = Ride.objects.all()    
        return render_to_response('rides/search.html', {'result_list':result_list}, context )
```

My Template:

```
{% for result in result_list %}
            <li>
            {% if result %}
                <a href="/rides/ridedetails/{{ result.pk }}">{{ result.type }}</a>
                <em>{{ result.ride_comment }}</em>
             {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
```

> I want do display the user details in the template, ie user_id and username from the Driver model of that associated ride_id. I have no idea how to get this!

Comment: The way you designed your models, you have a one-to-many relationship between Ride and Driver.  That is for a single Ride you have many drivers.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: How can one ride have many drivers? Your relationship sequence is inversed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have designed there is no direct way to access it. As its one-to-many type of relation.

though you can loop on `result.driver_set.all` and that will give you access to driver object access and you can fetch user_id access.

```
{% for result in result_list %}
            <li>
            {% if result %}
                <a href="/rides/ridedetails/{{ result.pk }}">{{ result.type }}</a>
                <em>{{ result.ride_comment }}</em>
                {% for item in result.driver_set.all %}
                  {{item.user_id}}
                {% endfor %}
             {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi I have tried the above code, I can get the username of the User object using this 'item.user_id'. But How can I access other User attributes like email. I have tried like 'item.user_id.email', but that is not working

Comment: I got it :) item.user_id.email gives the email, Earlier I dont have any value in the email field, so I got empty and thought the code is not worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Driver is actually the through table of a many-to-many relationship between Ride and User. You should make that explicit, by declaring a ManyToManyField on Ride:

```
 users = models.ManyToManyField(User, through=Driver)
```

Now you can access that relationship more directly in the template:

```
{% for result in result_list %}
  ...
  {% for user in result.users.all %}
    {{ user.username }}
  {% endif %}
```

Although I'd repeat what other comments have said: your relationship seems backwards, in that surely a ride should only have a single driver.